# Part of the code gets skipped

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to write my own little blog.
For this, I use the CodeIgniter framework.

In my blog posts, I also want to save a category and some keywords.
I need to be able to check if a category/keyword already exists, if not a new one needs to be created.
The ID of the existing/new one is saved to be used in a 'connecting' table.

I have the following database setup.

> **posts** - id (AI), title, date, content
>   **categories** - id (AI), category
>   **post_categories** - post, category
>   **keywords** - id (AI), keyword
>   **post_keywords** - post, keyword
>   *AI = Auto Increment

The tables posts, post_categories and post_keywords get updated, the tables categories and keywords remain empty. The category and keyword values in the connecting tables are ofc incorrect.

When troubleshooting my code, I echo'ed every variable in every step.
For some reason, the whole if/else structures checking whether a category or keyword already exists is skipped.

```
/**
 * Insert post into database
 * Check if category already exists, if not add it
 * Check if keywords already exist, if not add them
 * Insert post-category and post-keyword links
 * @param array $data
 * @return boolean success
 */
function create($data) {
    print_r($data);

    try {
        // posts
        $this->db->insert('posts', array(
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'date' => $data['date'],
            'content' => $data['content']
        ));

        $postId = $this->db->insert_id();

        echo '<p>Inserted new post (' . $data['title'] . ') at ' . $postId . '</p>';

        // category

        $category = $data['category'];

        $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category' => $category));

        $cat = 666;
        if ($this->db->count_all_results() == 1) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $cat = $row->id;
                echo '<p>cat = ' . $cat . '</p>';
            }
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('categories', array(
                'category' => $category
            ));
            $cat = $this->db->insert_id();
            echo '<p>cat = ' . $cat . '</p>';
        }

        echo '<p>Inserted new category (' . $category . ') at ' . $cat . '</p>';
        if($cat == 666) { echo ':('; }

        $this->db->insert('post_categories', array(
            'post' => $postId,
            'category' => $cat
        ));

        // keywords

        $keywords = $data['keywords'];

        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('keywords', array('keyword' => $keyword));

            $key = 666;
            if ($this->db->count_all_results() == 1) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $key = $row->id;
                    echo '<p>key = ' . $key . '</p>';
                }
            } else {
                $this->db->insert('keywords', array(
                    'keyword' => $keyword
                ));
                $key = $this->db->insert_id();
                echo '<p>key = ' . $key . '</p>';
            }

            echo '<p>Inserted new keyword (' . $keyword . ') at ' . $cat . '</p>';
            if($key == 666) { echo ':('; }

            $this->db->insert('post_keywords', array(
                'post' => $postId,
                'keyword' => $key
            ));
        }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print '<p>ERROR:</p>' . $e;

        return false;
    }
}
```

*Also in my controller*

```
echo '<p>' . ($this->m_posts->create($post) ? 'no errors :)' : 'error! :(') . '</p>';
```

**Result**

```
Array ( [title] => Foo Bar [date] => 2014-05-22 [content] => lorum ipsum dolore si amet [category] => Category [keywords] => Array ( [0] => Some [1] => Keywords ) )
Inserted new post (Foo Bar) at 2

Inserted new category (Category) at 666
:(

Inserted new keyword (Some) at 666
:(

Inserted new keyword (Keywords) at 666    
:(

no errors :)
```

**In my database**

```
POSTS

stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => Title [date] => 2014-05-22 [content] => okokokokokokok ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [title] => Foo Bar [date] => 2014-05-22 [content] => lorum ipsum dolore si amet ) 

CATEGORIES

POST_CATEGORIES

stdClass Object ( [post] => 1 [category] => 666 ) 
stdClass Object ( [post] => 2 [category] => 666 ) 

KEYWORDS

POST_KEYWORDS

stdClass Object ( [post] => 1 [keyword] => 666 ) 
stdClass Object ( [post] => 2 [keyword] => 666 ) 
stdClass Object ( [post] => 2 [keyword] => 666 )
```

*note:* I use 99 as a temp value to test if the variable was filled because I first thought the variable's value didn't leave the scope of the if/else. But echo'ing the values of the vars inside the if/else prints nothing. It seems to skip the whole if/else sections.

Comment: And it doest insert into post_categories with $cat = 99?

Comment: @Stefan yes, it uses the temporary value (99)

Comment: And should `$cat = $row()->id;` not be `$cat = $row->id;` ? Can you do a `print_r($row); exit;` there to see if you end up there?

Comment: @Stefan Damn, could be that I missed that, I rearranged some code. I'll have a look later today. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @Stefan It was indeed a mistake, but that line isn't even touched. That's why I didn't receive any error about it. Updated my post with some edits (echos) in the code and the result

Comment: `if ($this->db->count_all_results() == 1) {` is maybe true, but does it has to do with your `$query = $this->db->get_where`?
`$query->result()` maybe doesnt contain a record at all and that's why it looks like the if-else statment is skipped. Try `if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {` (I will adjust the code for you in an answer, more readable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the code to:

- In if statement num_rows of query it self
- If you expect 1 record do a `$query->row()` directly instead of a foreach loop.

  ```
  $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category' => $category));

  $cat = 666;
  if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
      $row = $query->row(); 
      $cat = $row->id;
      echo '<p>cat = ' . $cat . '</p>';
  } else {
      $this->db->insert('categories', array(
          'category' => $category
      ));
      $cat = $this->db->insert_id();
      echo '<p>cat = ' . $cat . '</p>';
  }
  ```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thank you so much for your help!